# Displaying most popular posts in the last week

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm unable to get this popular post code to output properly and instead I keep getting invalid arguments on my foreach which should just get the information from the array, and display the popular posts. However I'm not entirely sure as to why its the foreach loop is invalid as I have a similar setup for displaying recent posts.

Heres the code for the popular posts:

```
<?php

  $popular_post_args = array(
    'meta_key'  => 'post_views_count',
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'      => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => '1 week ago',
        ),
    ),
  );
  foreach( $popular_posts_args as $p ){
  ?>

   <div class="paddingarea text-dark">

     <div class="the-image" style="margin-top: -20px;">
         <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($p['ID']) ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($p['ID'], array(440, 240)); ?>"/></a>
     </div>

   <a class="posttitle" href="<?php echo get_permalink($p['ID']) ?>" style="font-weight: 600; font-size: 16px;"><span href="#" class="badge badge-primary" style="border-radius: 0;"><?php
   foreach(get_the_category($p['ID']) as $category) {
   echo $category->name;
 }
 ?></span>
 <?php echo $p['post_title']?></a><br />
   </div>

   <?php
   $authorname = get_the_author();

   echo '<p class="authortext">From ' . '<strong class="colorauthor">' . $authorname . '</strong>' . '</p>';

    ?>


   <?php
  }
 ?>
```

and here is the code for my recent posts:

```
<?php

$result = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
'numberposts' => 10,
'category' => '',
'post_status' => 'publish',
));

foreach( $result as $p ){
?>

<div class="paddingarea text-dark">

<div class="the-image" style="margin-top: -20px;">
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($p['ID']) ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($p['ID'], array(440, 240)); ?>"/></a>
</div>

<a class="posttitle" href="<?php echo get_permalink($p['ID']) ?>" style="font-weight: 600; font-size: 16px;"><span href="#" class="badge badge-primary" style="border-radius: 0;"><?php
foreach(get_the_category($p['ID']) as $category) {
echo $category->name;
}
?></span>
<?php echo $p['post_title']?></a><br />
</div>

<?php
$authorname = get_the_author();

echo '<p class="authortext">From ' . '<strong class="colorauthor">' . $authorname . '</strong>' . '</p>';

?>


<?php
}
?>
```

As you can see its basically the same code but just repurposed for displaying popular posts instead, however nothing displays and the top piece of code just gives out invaild foreach loop errors. So I'm not sure why its giving these because isn't it the same query being pulled by the array?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just have a typo. Your variable is defined as `$popular_post_args`. In your `foreach`, you are using `$popular_posts_args` which is not defined and hence the error.